# How to filter array item based on string with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, url, ecmascript-6

The purpose of `filter()` is to remove `currentGroup` matching with URLs from the array. It doesn't matter there is numbers after `Malappuram/123456/12` or not. Is there any best way to do it in ES6 ?

DEMO: https://jsbin.com/jozuqameto/edit?js,console

```js
const initialLinks = [
  "http://www.lchfmalayalam.com",
  "https://t.me/Malappuram",
  "https://t.me/keraladevelopers/42716",
  "http://www.whatsapp.com",
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnbFRSyHIl4",
  "http://google.com",
  "https://t.me/joinchat/NHNd1hcSMCoYlnZGSC_H7g",
  "https://t.me/keraladevelopers/",
  "http://t.me/keraladevelopers",
  "http://athimannil.com/react/",
  "http://athimannil.info/",
  "https://t.me/hellomates/5",
  "http://t.me/Malappuram/32156",
  "http://t.me/keraladevelopers/42716",
  "http://t.me/joinchat/NHNd1hcSMCoYlnZGSC_H7g",
  "http://t.me/keraladevelopers/",
  "http://t.me/hellomates/5"
];

const normalizeTme = R.replace(
  /^(?:@|(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:t\.me|telegram\.(?:me|dog))\/)(\w+)(\/.+)?/i,
  (_match, username, rest) => {
    return /^\/\d+$/.test(rest) ?
      `https://t.me/${username.toLowerCase()}` :
      `https://t.me/${username.toLowerCase()}${rest || ""}`;
  }
);

const filterOwnLinks = groupUsername => {
  return R.match(
    /^(?:@|(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:t\.me|telegram\.(?:me|dog))\/)(\w+)(\/.+)?/i,
    (_match, username, rest) => {
      if (username) {
        return currentGroup.toLowerCase() !== username.toLowerCase();
      }
      return true;
    }
  );
};

const currentGroup = "Malappuram";

const urls = R.uniq(initialLinks)
  .filter(filterOwnLinks)
  .map(normalizeTme);

console.log(initialLinks);
console.log(urls);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How complex is the content of `currentGroup`? Do you really need Regular Expressions or is a good ol' [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) operation enough?

Comment: It is actually for Telegram Bot, the `currentGroup` may vary at based on group name. The purpose is to filter link of the same group name related.

Comment: Does the current group always appear after `http://websitname.domain/currentGroup`   ? or it can be at any place in URL ?

Comment: @CodeManiac group name always coming after `http://t.me/`

Comment: @Mo. you can use URL api, and take pathname from parsed url and check if it starts with currentGroup

Answer (score 1):

You can use `URL` api to parse url, and take the pathname from parse url object, and check if starts with `currentGroup`

```js
const initialLinks = ["http://www.lchfmalayalam.com","https://t.me/Malappuram","https://t.me/keraladevelopers/42716","http://www.whatsapp.com","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnbFRSyHIl4","http://google.com","https://t.me/joinchat/NHNd1hcSMCoYlnZGSC_H7g","https://t.me/keraladevelopers/","http://t.me/keraladevelopers","http://athimannil.com/react/","http://athimannil.info/","https://t.me/hellomates/5","http://t.me/Malappuram/32156","http://t.me/keraladevelopers/42716","http://t.me/joinchat/NHNd1hcSMCoYlnZGSC_H7g","http://t.me/keraladevelopers/","http://t.me/hellomates/5"];
const currentGroup = "Malappuram";
const urls = [...new Set(initialLinks)]

let final = urls.filter(url => {
  let parsed = new URL(url)
  let pattern = new RegExp(`^\/${currentGroup}`,'i')
  return !pattern.test(parsed.pathname)
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Actually I need to get the result with all links except `currentGroup`. Just make change `!pattern.test(parsed.pathname)` will be okay isn't ? ?

Comment: what if we use `.startsWith()` ?

Comment: @Mo. yes you can there are many ways you can achieve same thing, if you want to use startsWith you need to change case of both `pathname` and `currentGroup` to achieve case insensitivity, `parsed.pathname.toLowerCase(\`\/${currentGroup.toLowerCase()}\`)`

Answer (score 1):

You could [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) with a simple regular expression within the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) callback:

```js
const initialLinks = [
  "http://www.lchfmalayalam.com",
  "https://t.me/Malappuram",
  "https://t.me/keraladevelopers/42716",
  "http://www.whatsapp.com",
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnbFRSyHIl4",
  "http://google.com",
  "https://t.me/joinchat/NHNd1hcSMCoYlnZGSC_H7g",
  "https://t.me/keraladevelopers/",
  "http://t.me/keraladevelopers",
  "http://athimannil.com/react/",
  "http://athimannil.info/",
  "https://t.me/hellomates/5",
  "http://t.me/Malappuram/32156",
  "http://t.me/keraladevelopers/42716",
  "http://t.me/joinchat/NHNd1hcSMCoYlnZGSC_H7g",
  "http://t.me/keraladevelopers/",
  "http://t.me/hellomates/5"
];

const getCurrentGroupLinks = (links, regex) => {
  return links.filter(link => !regex.test(link));
};

console.log(getCurrentGroupLinks(initialLinks, /Malappuram/));
```